# No music folder access. - Oops, something went wrong. How, why & what?

Tags: directory, music

Since upgrade to 20.04 I have no Music folder access. - Oops, something went wrong comes back if I click it. How, why & what? Anyone know a remedy? Music folder only exists as a title. There is no access to or display of any contents yet a music file from elsewhere can be played by RhythmBox.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide more info, it's attracting close votes for lacking specifics. For example, does your Music folder exist, and you just can't access it? Or is it gone completely? How are you trying to access it?

Comment: "Unable to find the requested file Please check the spelling",........Music.   Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What does this mean "Music folder only exists as a title"?

Comment: It means it does not lead anywhere when clicked and shows no content- just the words Music Folder

Comment: In your file manager or what? Please be explicit, no one can read your mind.

Comment: After a fresh instillation of Ubuntu 20.04 the only sound was from Rythmbox. Entering “pulsecontrol –start” in the Terminal would restore all the sound but has to be reentered on next boot..  Reinstalling Pulseaudio made no difference. The folders Pictures, Documents, Videos. contained the expected but Music returned "Oops. “Something Went Wrong “and told me to check my spelling.  I am sure its non-functioning is caused by more than my spelling.
Is there a Sound issue with Ubuntu 20.04; there was no problem with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: .............that should be "pulseaudio -- start" not pulsecontrol

Comment: Re existence  of Music folder: clicking on it just displays Oops,,,,Does that mean it exists?